# Save LogCat entries in SQLite-Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-logcat

Is it possible to save a logcat entry in a sqlite database?
If a user got an error I want to read the logs without having the phone connected to adb.

This is how I write logs: `Log.d(TAG, "An error occured", e)`

Thanks

Comment: why dont you use a [crash reporting library](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary) (if you are publishing it)? It will send a mail when app is crashed with relevant crash log

Comment: An error can occure without crashing the app

Comment: You can use instabug https://instabug.com/. which will provide full details of the crash

Comment: the app is not crashing

Comment: see `java.util.logging.Handler`

Comment: Hi, I have an exact similar requirements for the all I am working on,  If you have found any solution to this  please let me know.

Comment: I'm using Firebase Crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

Creating a log file will be better option to read error

```
public void mlogFile(String pActivityName, String pOperation, String pData) {
        File lLogFilePath, lLogFile;
        Date lDate;
        CharSequence lCurrfolder;
        FileWriter lFileWriter;
        BufferedWriter lBuffWriter;
        String lActivity, lOperation;
        try {
            lDate = new Date();
            lCurrfolder = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd", lDate.getTime());
            lLogFilePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "CSPDCLData/" + lCurrfolder + "/");
            if (!lLogFilePath.exists()) {
                lLogFilePath.mkdirs();
            }
            lLogFile = new File(lLogFilePath, "ADDLogfile.txt");
            lFileWriter = new FileWriter(lLogFile, true);
            lBuffWriter = new BufferedWriter(lFileWriter);
            lActivity = pActivityName.length() != 0 ? ADDPadding(pActivityName, 25, ' ', 'L') + "~ " : "";
            lOperation = pOperation.length() != 0 ? " : " + pData : "";
            lBuffWriter.append(DateFormat.format("kk:mm:ss", lDate.getTime()) + " " + lActivity + pOperation + lOperation + "\n");
            lBuffWriter.flush();
            lBuffWriter.close();
            lFileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And at the time of error add this line

```
logFile(getClass().getSimpleName(),"methodName()", "An error occured"+ e.getMessage());
```

Comment: why should a file be better than a database?

Comment: No need to chek into database you can see in external storage only. you see it as a text file anywhere